# Show 3 numbers only before and after of an exact number in a post-increment

Tags: php, post-increment

I am not sure how to ask this question. If I knew exactly what to look for, I might not have to post here. I will explain the situation, I hope you guys can tell me what exactly to look for(or what type of function).
This is a code I am working on -

```
$walkaround_pages = 15;
$walkaround_page = $_GET['walkaround_page'];
for ($wp = 1; $wp <= $walkaround_pages; $wp++) {
    echo '<a class="pagination_links'.(($wp==$walkaround_page)?' current_page':"").'" href="/panel/?walkaround_page='.$wp.'">'.$wp.'</a>';
}
```

This generates pagination links. When the number of total pages(`$walkaround_pages`) are more than 10, it can't fit in the mobile devices. So I want to make something like if current page (`$walkaround_page`) is let's say 7, it will only show 3 numbers before (4,5,6) and 3 numbers after(8,9,10) instead of showing all the numbers 1 through 15.
Can anyone please tell me what exactly I am looking for?

Comment: Sounds like something that could (should?) be solved with CSS's [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) rule.

Comment: it could be solved with css, also with JS but i wanted to load only the links that would appear, not load everything and stop displaying some other links. @Accountant م answer was what I was looking for

Comment: All good! Personally I like dynamic content displays that allows the most flexibility to the user. With just how dynamic screens are these days (rotations, 2 in 1 displays, browser tabs being dragged and snapped to window edges), a fluid design is very helpful. Doing something like this in PHP is very restricted or requires a call back to the server.

Comment: I like your thinking. I will try to rely more on css which can be done with css instead of giving server more pressure. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work out the start and end parts of the loop relative to the page your currently on and just loop over that...

```
$walkaround_pages = 15;
$max_gap = 3;      // How many pages before and after you want
$walkaround_page = $_GET['walkaround_page'];
$start = max(1,$walkaround_page-$max_gap);
$end = min($walkaround_pages,$walkaround_page+$max_gap);
for ($wp = $start; $wp <= $end; $wp++) {
```

With start, it's a case of subtract the number of items, but make sure that 1 is the lowest it can go, similar with end is add the number of pages but limited to the total number of pages.

Comment: Your approach is more performant as it saves unnecessary loop iterations

Comment: Agree with @Accountantم

Answer (score 1):

Just add a condition before you echo

```
if( abs($wp - $walkaround_page) <= 3){
        echo '<a class="pagination_links'.(($wp==$walkaround_page)?' current_page':"").'" href="/panel/?walkaround_page='.$wp.'">'.$wp.'</a>';
}
```

the [abs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) function will return the absolute value so it returns positive number if it is one of the 3 smaller or bigger numbers than the current page

see [live demo](https://eval.in/1070045)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CSS example using the [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) rule.

The great part about this is you could make it a very fluid design. For example, when a user rotates their device, the extra links will be displayed.

Same if the the user resizes a browser window.

```css
.wide a, .narrow a {
  padding:0px 0.5em;
}
.wide a:hover, .narrow a:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background:#345;
}

/* this would be in your @media rule */
/* @media screen and (max-width: 480px) { */ 
.narrow a:nth-of-type(n+6) {
  display:none;
}
/* } */
```

```html
<p>For demonstration only</p>
<div class="wide">
<a href="#">1</a> <a href="#">2</a> <a href="#">3</a>
<a href="#">4</a> <a href="#">5</a> <a href="#">6</a>
<a href="#">7</a> <a href="#">8</a> <a href="#">9</a>
<a href="#">10</a>
</div>

<p>Below is all you would have</p>
<div class="narrow">
<a href="#">1</a> <a href="#">2</a> <a href="#">3</a>
<a href="#">4</a> <a href="#">5</a> <a href="#">6</a>
<a href="#">7</a> <a href="#">8</a> <a href="#">9</a>
<a href="#">10</a>
</div>
```